# Regex/Gsub removing all nested double quotes instead of just the outer ones

Tags: json, ruby, csv, gsub

I want to import the following CSV into rails db:

```
"[{""id"":""actions"",""name"":""app"",""description""}]"
```

After importing, I always get:

```
"{\"id\":\"actions\",\"name\":\"app\",\"description\"]}"
```

I want the import to looks like this:

```
[{"id":,"actions":,"name":,"description",...}]"
```

I tried using `.gsub!(/"/,'')` but this returns:

```
"[{id:actions,name:actions,description:}]"
```

> The issue is that all the quote marks have been removed so its just `id` insted of `"id"`

My code is:

```
def import_app_version
  path = Rails.root.join('db', 'csv_export', 'app_versions.csv')
  counter = 0
  puts "Inserts on table app_versions started..."


  CSV.foreach(path, headers: true) do |row|
    next if row.to_hash['modules'] == nil
    row.to_hash['modules'].gsub!(/"/,'')
    next if row.to_hash['deleted_at'] != nil
    counter += 1
    AppVersion.skip_callbacks = true
    AppVersion.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
  AppVersion.skip_callbacks = false
  puts "#{counter} inserts on table app_versions complete"
end
```

What is the right way to do this so that the import works correctly and the data is imported as it's meant to be?

I have been searching for half a day, and found so many answers but they all end up removing all of the double quotes as displayed above.

Or even better would be, if someone knew a way to import csv with JSON content the right way.

Comment: I am not sure what your intention is here but your data shown is horribly inconsistent and does not represent valid objects at any point. e.g. First String shows what appears to be an Array with an invalid Hash; 2nd String shows what appears to be an invalid Hash with a errant closing bracket "]" thrown in; Third Whatever it is shows an Array with an invalid Hash with a errant colon in the middle and an errant double quote at the end plus it loses the "app" String somewhere along the way. Basically none of the transformations make sense. Please fix the question and the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use replace, or do not try to remove quotes manually.

```
"[{""id"":""actions"",""name"":""app"",""description""}]"
```

If you read the above data with a csv parser/reader (maybe with a parameter 'quoted fields') all should be fine.

The surrounding quotes will be removed and the inside quotes will be unescaped to one double quote.